# SQL query with where condition using Expression<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, sql-server, repository-pattern

In my project, I have a three layers like this.

**Repository Layer**

```
IEnumerable<Tag> IRepository<Tag>.GetMany(Expression<Func<Tag, bool>> where)
{
    Expression<Func<Tag, bool>> cat = where; 
    //what to do here with where variable to get the value.

    using (var cmd = DbContext.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Id, Name, UrlSlug, Description, DateAdded, UserId from Tag"; // where UserId = @UserId";
        //cmd.AddParameter("@UserId", UserId);
         return ToList(cmd);
     }
 }
```

**Service Layer code**

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetMany(Expression<Func<Category, bool>> where)
{
    return _repository.GetMany(where);
}
```

**Code Behind Method called at PageLoad event**

```
void BindGrid()
{
   var categories = Service.GetMany(c => c.User.UserId == Guid.Parse(Session["guid"].ToString()));
   gvCategory.DataSource = categories;
   gvCategory.DataBind();
}
```

Now this function is returning all results from the database, but is has to return only the records `where userId = @UserId`. I want it to return only rows that are related with the user only (not all of them).

Please guide me how it can be achieved. I am using Expression for the first time. Thanks

Comment: `Expression<Func<Tag, bool>>` is meant to encapsulate your query criteria. So, instead of querying yourself using SQL string, you need to pass that expression to the proper `DbContext` method. Perhaps: `DbContext.Tags.Where(where)`

Comment: The project does not use any ORM tool, it is done using Ado.Net with fixed SQL queries, stored procedures and parameters. It does not have  `DbContext` class at all. It just has a `SqlHelper` class which is used for any database read and write. I was trying to make it somewhat better using latest c# constructs. Is there any way to achieve it with the current situation?

Comment: Then you'll have to parse the `Expression` yourself and generate the appropriate SQL. In LINQ terms, that's typically the role of the LINQ provider and it's no easy task (unless you're going to pass a *very* simple predicates).